# Any scenarios where Meteor.js autopublish would actually be useful?

Tags: performance, meteor

Lately I've been getting more and more interested in Meteor.js. At the moment I'm developing a new web project of mine. What I can't get out of my mind is the Autopublish feature of Meteor. At the moment of writing my MongoDB has a total of 32453 records, therefore, as you can probably guess I had to turn off autopublish and subscribe/publish manually.

I've read a mouthful of guides now and it seems to be a completely common practice to turn off autopublish as soon as your application is created. This makes me question - does the feature have any practical use in a real world scenario? I can see it being useful for the shock and awe effect of the examples, but aside from that, it seems more or less pointless. I might be missing something very obvious though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Autopublish is designed to be turned off before production. It's simply a feature to speed up development in the early stages, and that's all. From the Meteor Docs:

> By default, a new Meteor app includes the autopublish and insecure packages, which together mimic the effect of each client having full read/write access to the server's database. These are useful prototyping tools, but typically not appropriate for production applications. When you're ready, just remove the packages.

Answer (score 3):

You are not missing anything. It was added to make the examples work and to get users up and running quickly when working on new projects. I can't think of a compelling reason for a production app to have autopublish on.